# only part of task executed when connection lost on redis using django celery

Tags: django, python-3.x, redis, celery, django-celery

I have a django celery task that is only partly executing.

I start up the app and the connection looks good:

> INFO/MainProcess] Connected to
>   redis://elasticache.cache.amazonaws.com:6379/0 [2018-02-17
>   23:27:24,314: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
>   [2018-02-17 23:27:25,339: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
>   [2018-02-17 23:27:25,604: INFO/MainProcess]
>   worker1@test_vmstracker_com ready.

I initiate the process and the task is received an executed:

> [2018-02-17 23:27:49,810: INFO/MainProcess] Received task:
>   tracking.tasks.escalate[92f54d48202]  ETA:[2018-02-18
>   07:27:59.797380+00:00]  [2018-02-17 23:27:49,830: INFO/MainProcess]
>   Received task: tracking.tasks.escalate[09a0aebef72b]  ETA:[2018-02-18
>   07:28:19.809712+00:00]  [2018-02-17 23:28:00,205:
>   WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-7] -my app is working-

Then I start getting errors and it doesn't finish the task where my app sends an email

> [2018-02-17 23:28:00,214: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-7] Connection to Redis
>   lost: Retry (0/20) now. [2018-02-17 23:28:00,220:
>   ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-7] Connection to Redis lost: Retry (1/2

**Does anyone know why only have executes and then the connection is lost?**

Here is the full stacktrace:

```
[2018-02-17 23:28:19,382: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-7] /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py:549: RuntimeWarning: Exception raised outside body: ConnectionError("Error while reading from socket: ('Connection closed by server.',)",):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 177, in _read_from_socket
    raise socket.error(SERVER_CLOSED_CONNECTION_ERROR)
OSError: Connection closed by server.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 2879, in execute
    return execute(conn, stack, raise_on_error)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 2764, in _execute_transaction
    self.parse_response(connection, '_')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 2838, in parse_response
    self, connection, command_name, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 680, in parse_response
    response = connection.read_response()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 624, in read_response
    response = self._parser.read_response()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 284, in read_response
    response = self._buffer.readline()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 216, in readline
    self._read_from_socket()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 191, in _read_from_socket
    (e.args,))
redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error while reading from socket: ('Connection closed by server.',)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 177, in _read_from_socket
    raise socket.error(SERVER_CLOSED_CONNECTION_ERROR)
OSError: Connection closed by server.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 434, in trace_task
    uuid, retval, task_request, publish_result,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 152, in mark_as_done
    self.store_result(task_id, result, state, request=request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 309, in store_result
    request=request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 652, in _store_result
    self.set(self.get_key_for_task(task_id), self.encode(meta))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/backends/redis.py", line 213, in set
    return self.ensure(self._set, (key, value), **retry_policy)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/backends/redis.py", line 203, in ensure
    **retry_policy)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/utils/functional.py", line 333, in retry_over_time
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/backends/redis.py", line 222, in _set
    pipe.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 2894, in execute
    return execute(conn, stack, raise_on_error)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 2764, in _execute_transaction
    self.parse_response(connection, '_')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 2838, in parse_response
    self, connection, command_name, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 680, in parse_response
    response = connection.read_response()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 624, in read_response
    response = self._parser.read_response()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 284, in read_response
    response = self._buffer.readline()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 216, in readline
    self._read_from_socket()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 191, in _read_from_socket
    (e.args,))
redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error while reading from socket: ('Connection closed by server.',)

  exc, exc_info.traceback)))
```

Comment: Seems like redis closed the connection, try to update to latest redis server and also redis the python package

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my app server and broker instances were too small.  I'm using ec2.  As soon as I upgraded to the large hardware, the problem went away. Either the ec2 instance or elasticache instance was too small in terms of CPU, memory, and network.