# Not able to run airflow task using airflow plugin

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer, google-cloud-scheduler

I've got gcloud composer airflow instance and custom airflow web plugin which runs separate job on specific endpoint. Airflow version is 1.14 (1.14+composer in the cloud)

```
@rest_api_decorator('/run_task', "POST")
def trigger_tasks(self):
        dag_id = Util.get_argument(request, 'dag_id')
        task_id = Util.get_argument(request, 'task_id')
        subdir = Util.get_argument(request, 'subdir')
        execution_date = parsedate(Util.get_argument(request, 'execution_date'))

        dag = self.get_dag(subdir, dag_id)

        task = dag.get_task(task_id=task_id)
        ti = TaskInstance(task, execution_date)
        ti.refresh_from_db()
        ti_list.append(ti)

        executor = get_default_executor()
        executor.start()
        executor.queue_task_instance(
                ti,
                ignore_all_deps=True)
        executor.heartbeat()
        executor.end()

        result = {
            'dag_id': dag_id,
            'task_id': task_id_list
        }

        return Util.get_response(result)
```

Listing above is an example of the endpoint of web plugin. This code works flowlessly on my local instance with celery executor but for some reason it doesn't work in the cloud.
From log files I clearly can see that the task is being added to the queue:

```
2021-04-28T16:17:04.962251133Zairflow-webserver [2021-04-28 16:17:01,054] {base_executor.py:58} INFO - Adding to queue: ['airflow', 'run', 'tutorial', 'print_date', '2021-04-23T09:18:11+00:00', '-A', '--local', '--pool', 'default_pool', '-sd', 'DAGS_FOLDER/
```

But then there are multiple errors indicating that operation above didn't complete successfully:

```
[2021-04-28 16:23:27,934] {redis.py:363} ERROR - Connection to Redis lost: Retry (0/20) now.@-@{"workflow": "tutorial", "task-id": "print_date", "execution-date": "2021-04-23T09:18:13+00:00"}
```

I was able to run separate task using gcloud cli but for some reason similar code doesn't execute in the plugin.
Am I missing something?

Update

Here is screenshot of worker workload
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHUv6.png

Comment: Could you tell me what type of machine you are using ?

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes
web server:
composer-n1-webserver-2 (2 vCPU, 1.6 GB memory),
airflow gke:
n1-standard-1

Comment: also I changed operation_timeout celery parameter to 15, so now it waits 15 sec and then fails like before

Comment: The machine type you are using seems to be running out of memory because of the high resources demand when connecting to Redis. Could you create a new environment with a higher [machine type](https://cloud.google.com/composer/pricing#machine-type)? Then test your tasks with it. Please let me know if it worked.

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes do you mean to change airflow gke machine type?

Comment: When you create your composer environment you select a machine type, [here](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/creating#creating_a_new_environment). Could you create a new environment and test it with your tasks?

Comment: Please let me know if it worked.

Comment: Working on new composer environment. Will let you know soon.

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes re-tested on new composer env with better machine type - the same result, same errors in logs

Comment: Which machine type have you used for the new test?

Comment: Looks like n1-standard-4 (4 CPU and 15 GB RAM). I believe it shouldn't be memory issue, as same same operation works from gcloud cli

Comment: can you check the airflow-worker memory utilisation and share a print screen in your question? You can check it under ***Kubernetes Engine> Workloads> Filter by your Composer environment's name***.

Comment: updated question with screenshot

Comment: Could you check the memory graph for your for your Pod as well? To see if there are any spikes. Also, there is a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48849470/only-part-of-task-executed-when-connection-lost-on-redis-using-django-celery).

Comment: Unfortunately I wasn't able to spot any spikes. Could you please direct me how I can check memory usage graph for specific pod? And which pod specifically I should check? Worker?

Comment: You can go to `Stackdriver > Metrics Explorer > Resource Type: Kubernetes Container > Metric: Memory usage > Filter: cluster_name= your_cluster_name > Group by: cluster_name`. Then you can also group by `pod_name` and check the utilisation for both. Have u spotted any spikes?

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes haven't found any obvious spikes using provided instructions. Tried to group by both cluster name and pod name

Comment: Unfortunately from here I can't debug more. However, you can open an Issue in [Google Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker) where it will be further investigated. Please when creating a case there provide as much details as possible, including the graph's printscreen.

Comment: Thank you, will certainly proceed with Google Issue Tracker

Answer (score 0):

Figured out with Google Cloud support that it's not possible to queue task in composer environment in such a way. As a workaround, simple "wrapper" dag can be created, that will contain bash operator to submit separate tasks using cli.